# How can I load .glb model from server in scene 1.16.0

Tags: android-augmented-reality

This is my code but 3d model not showing after tracking.

```
placeObject(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), Uri.parse("http://vzor.ir/model.glb"));

private void placeObject(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Uri uri) {
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(arFragment.getContext(), uri)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable))
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Error:" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return null;
                    }

            );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit my placeObject function and works it.

```
private void placeObject(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Uri uri) {
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(arFragment.getContext(), RenderableSource.builder().setSource(arFragment.getContext(), uri, RenderableSource.sourceType.GLB).build())
            .build()
            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable))
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                        Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Error:" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return null;
                    }

            );
}
```